# Why string inputs after integer input gets skipped in Java?

Tags: java

I am trying to input values of certain string and integer variables in Java.
But if I am taking the input of string after the integer, in the console the string input is just skipped and moves to the next input.

Here is the code

```
String name1;
int id1,age1;

Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);

//I can input name if input is before all integers

System.out.println("Enter id");
id1 = in.nextInt();


System.out.println("Enter name");       //Problem here, name input gets skipped
name1 = in.nextLine();

System.out.println("Enter age");
age1 = in.nextInt();
```

Comment: You can use `next` method to accept string.

Comment: @VighaneshGursale This will take only the first string, not the full line, and it's different from the posted code.

Comment: @enrico.bacis I agree with you

Answer (score 38, accepted):

This is a common problem, and it happens because the [`nextInt`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html#nextInt()) method doesn't read the newline character of your input, so when you issue the command [`nextLine`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html#nextLine()), the Scanner finds the newline character and gives you that as a line.

A workaround could be this one:

```
System.out.println("Enter id");
id1 = in.nextInt();

in.nextLine();   // skip the newline character

System.out.println("Enter name");
name1 = in.nextLine();
```

Another way would be to always use [`nextLine`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html#nextLine()) wrapped into a `Integer.parseInt`:

```
int id1;
try {
    System.out.println("Enter id");
    id1 = Integer.parseInt(input.nextLine());
} catch (NumberFormatException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
System.out.println("Enter name");
name1 = in.nextLine();
```

#### Why not just `Scanner.next()` ?

I would not use [`Scanner.next()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html#nextInt()) because this will read only the next token and not the full line. For example the following code:

```
System.out("Enter name: ");
String name = in.next();
System.out(name);
```

will produce:

```
Enter name: Mad Scientist
Mad
```

It will not process *Scientist* because *Mad* is already a completed token per se.
So maybe this is the expected behavior for your application, but it has a different semantic from the code you posted in the question.

Answer (score 2):

This is your updated working code.

```
 package myPackage;

    import java.util.Scanner;

    public class test {

        /**
         * @param args
         */
        public static void main(String[] args) {
            String name1;
            int id1,age1;

            Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);

            //I can input name if input is before all integers

            System.out.println("Enter id");
            id1 = in.nextInt();


            System.out.println("Enter name");       //Problem here, name input gets skipped
            name1 = in.next();

            System.out.println("Enter age");
            age1 = in.nextInt();

        }

    }
```

Answer (score 1):

May be you try this way..

Instead of this code

```
       System.out.println("Enter name");       //Problem here, name input gets skipped
       name1 = in.nextLine();
```

try this

```
       System.out.println("Enter name");      
       name1 = in.next();
```

Comment: You are right, looser! :P :D :L

Comment: @VishnuPrasadKallummel This has a different semantic from your question code. It will take only the first token, so if your name has a space it will take the first part only. Check also my answer to understand why.

Comment: @enrico.bacis - Yes, you are right, it does not consider anything after a space.