# Always getting the same answer in java

Tags: java, arrays, arraylist, collections, java.util.scanner

Can anyone explain to me why I get only 40 as answer when I run the following code?

[View problem in code coach](https://www.sololearn.com/coach/18?ref=app)

```java
    import java.util.*;
    public class Program
    {
        public static void main(String[] args) {
            Scanner var = new Scanner (System.in);
            String n = var.nextLine();
            int p = var.nextInt();
            String[] a = var.nextLine().split(" ");
            List<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
            for(int i=0;i<a.length;i++){
                list.add(a[i]);
            }
            list.add(n);
            Collections.sort(list);
            int y = list.indexOf(n)+1;
            if(y>p){
                System.out.print(((y/p)*20)+(y%p)*20);
            }
            else{
                System.out.print("20");
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. It's not clear what the code is intended to do - you haven't explained it in the question, and there are no comments. Have you tried stepping through your code in a debugger, so you can work out at what point it behaves differently to how you expect it to?

Comment: Please an input example ;)

Comment: The link you have given is broken. What inputs you have tried? i get both 20 and 40 for different inputs.

Comment: `nextInt()` is not consuming the ENTER (newline) when the entry is made and therefore allowing the `String[] a = var.nextLine().split(" ");` to absorb it and therefore never get really called for what it was intended. Place `var.nextLine();` directly after `int p = var.nextInt();` so it looks like this `int p = var.nextInt(); var.nextLine();`.

Comment: The link will open only in phones but not on PC

Comment: @DevilsHnd Yes, you are right brother. It was the real problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

nextInt() cannot read newline character. so when you use nextLine() it reads that new line character.
[This answer might help you](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26626106/why-string-inputs-after-integer-input-gets-skipped-in-java)